# Error resolving template, when I am not even asking for one

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I am getting a very odd issue. When sending a post request using `ajax` to my Spring Controller, even though I am not returning anything, I am getting the following error.

> Error resolving template "poliza/modificar-distribucion", template
>   might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured
>   Template Resolvers

**Here is my Controller's code.**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/poliza")
public class EntryController {

    // Some other methods and the @Autowired services.

    @PostMapping(value = "/modificar-distribucion")
    public void updateEntryDistribution(@RequestBody EntryDistribution entryDistribution) throws Exception {
        entryDistributionService.updateDistribution(entryDistribution);
    }

}
```

**This is my jQuery code.**

```
// Return the distribution object for each cell.
function getDistributionObject(cell) {

    // Some logic.

    // Return the object.
    return {
        entryDistributionID: {
            entryID: id,
            productCode: productCode,
            sizeFK: size,
            sizeType: sizeType,
            storeId: storeId
        },
        quantity: integerValue,
        entryHeader: null
    }

}

function sendRequest(distributionObject, cell) {

    // Some logic.

    $.ajax({
            url: "/poliza/modificar-distribucion",
            data: JSON.stringify(distributionObject),
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            success: function() {
                // Now, let's set the default value to the actual value.
                $(cell).attr('default-value', quantity);
            }, error: function(error) {
                // Send a notification indicating that something went wrong.
                // Only if it is not an abort.
                if(error.statusText === "Abort") return;
                errorNotification(error.responseJSON.message);
            }
    }));
}
```

**My service code.**

```
@Override
public void updateDistribution(EntryDistribution entryDistribution) throws Exception {

    // First, let's see if the distribution exists.
    EntryDistribution oldEntryDistribution = this.findById(entryDistribution.getEntryDistributionID());
    if(oldEntryDistribution == null) {
        // If not, insert it.
        this.insert(entryDistribution);
    } else {
        // Else, update it.
        this.update(entryDistribution);
    }

}
```

**Entry distribution object.**

```
public class EntryDistribution {

    private EntryDistributionID entryDistributionID;
    private Integer quantity;
    private EntryHeader entryHeader;

    // Getters and setters.
}

public class EntryDistributionID implements Serializable {

    private Long entryID;
    private String productCode;
    private String sizeFK;
    private String sizeType;
    private String storeId;

    // Getters and setters.
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? I shouldn't be getting this error, since I am not trying to fetch any Thymeleaf template in this particular call.

Comment: can you post your controller class as well as distributionObject in jquery

Comment: @NegiRox I just edited my question with the required information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should return something instead of void so that ajax can know whether the call was successful or not(change method return type from void to boolean or string).

Because you have not specify the response content type so spring is trying to find html page.

To resolve that tell spring to return JSON response by adding @ResponseBody annotation on top of method like below.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/modificar-distribucion")
@ResponseBody
public String updateEntryDistribution(@RequestBody EntryDistribution entryDistribution) throws Exception {
        entryDistributionService.updateDistribution(entryDistribution);
        return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you replace your code with this and try.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/modificar-distribucion")
public void updateEntryDistribution(@RequestBody EntryDistribution entryDistribution) throws Exception {
    entryDistributionService.updateDistribution(entryDistribution);
}



@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/modificar-distribucion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Boolean updateEntryDistribution(@RequestBody EntryDistribution entryDistribution) {
    return true;
}
```

also check JSON object which you are passing must be same as POJO attributes